# how to insert yes/or in the database based on chexkbox checked or unchecked

Tags: sql, vb.net, checkbox

How to add Yes or no in the database using a check box based on check or uncheck
if check then Yes and vice versa.?

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
    If CheckBox1.Checked Then
        Dim dbprovider As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Taher\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\Database1.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
        Me.con = New OleDb.OleDbConnection()
        con.ConnectionString = dbprovider
        con.Open()

        Dim sqlquery As String = "INSERT INTO Company (dev)" + "VALUES ('" Yes "')
        Dim sqlcommand As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sqlquery)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What is column type for column "dev"

Comment: Use the IIF function with Yes if checked, No if not http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27ydhh0d(v=vs.71).aspx. Furthermore your concatenation and unclosed quotes of the sqlQuery is going to result both compile errors and your sql driver rejecting the command

Comment: text or string @AshReva

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this way

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged

    Dim dbprovider As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Taher\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\Database1.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
    Me.con = New OleDb.OleDbConnection()
    con.ConnectionString = dbprovider
    con.Open()
    Dim sqlquery As String

    sqlquery = "Insert into Company (dev) values ('" + IIf(CheckBox1.Checked, "yes", "no") + "')"

    Dim sqlcommand As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sqlquery)
    sqlcommand.executeNonQuery()
```

End Sub

Comment: Tried this way----didnt insert into the database

Comment: @user1897472 also can you paste what string your get when you execute your code. Check what string you get from sqlquery in debug mode

Comment: i want to run two string at the hit of an add button sqlquery and sqlquery1 sqlquery has some data and sqlquery has the checkbox data if we do it differently they are storing the data in a new instance instaed of the same row can we run both querys at the hit of the add button this is the code for the querys http://jsfiddle.net/jG2eY/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24966/discussion-between-user1897472-and-ashreva)

Answer (score 1):

Use the sql type `BIT` to represent False (0) or True (1). You can use the words TRUE and FALSE to insert the data.

Answer (score 1):

Checkboxes are by nature boolean inputs. You can store their value in a database using quite some approaches, these are the most common:
- boolean field (true/false)
- numeric field ( 1 for true and 0 for false )

use the boolean keywords TRUE and FALSE

TRUE is equal to yes
FALSE equals no

```
UPDATE tablename SET field1 = TRUE, field2 = FALSE;

INSERT INTO tablename SET field1 = TRUE, field2 = FALSE ;
```

Hope this helps